# is GuidedStepFragment for android Mobile or only android TV?

Tags: android, leanback

The fragment is included in `android.support.v17.leanback.app.GuidedStepFragment` which is apart of Leanback library.

I think Leanback is for Android TV, will `GuidedStepFragment` work if i try to implement it in a mobile device?

Here is an example of the fragment in action: https://youtu.be/RhXuihvQ4Lg

Comment: its only for tv not for mobile device. but you can grab code from tv sample and develop for mobile but as per documentation its not right way to use tv design in mobile or tablets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leanback is a library specifically designed for TV, as stated on [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v17-leanback):

> **v17 Leanback Library**
>   The android.support.v17.leanback package provides APIs to support building user interfaces on TV devices. It
>   provides a number of important widgets for TV apps.

But Nothing prevent you to use the widgets available in the library in your mobile app for Android 4.2 and higher. You will probably have to make some adaptations since the Android TV have a different kind of interaction (TV remote and game controller) compared to the mobile device.

You can make a quick test of the GuidedStepFragment running the [Android TV Leanback example](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback) on your mobile device and selecting:

```
More Samples > Guided Step First
```

Comment: so you in android studio can i go to import samples and find the Guided Step First there ? i dont see it.

Comment: Yes, import `TV Leanback Support Library sample - Videos by Google` and then you can find the Activity `com.example.android.tvleanback.ui.GuidedStepActivity` where the `GuidedStepFragment` are used.